# Set focus on inputbox on page start HTML

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I have an issue with html page. I want to set focus on the first input box when the page loads but all my attempts to do so ended in failure. I'm not sure what I've been doing incorrectly since I'm not frontend dev. Will anyone be willing to send a hint what's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Product Input</title>
    <style>
        /* Modal styles */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            width: 400px;
            max-width: 90%;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        .modal-content {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        /* Center all other elements */
        body, h1, form, input, ul {
            text-align: center;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        input[type="submit"],
        button {
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        /* Additional styling for different screen resolutions */
        @media (max-width: 480px) {
            body {
                font-size: 16px;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1350px) {
            body {
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 1351px) {
            body {
                font-size: 24px;
            }
        }
        .logout-button {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Product Input</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <label for="user_input_1">Enter First Input:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="user_input_1" name="user_input_1" required>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p style="color: red;">{{ error }}</p>
    <!-- Logout button -->
    {% if 'username' in session %}
        <a class="logout-button" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
    {% endif %}
    
    <h2>Added Inputs:</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for item in user_inputs %}
            <li>{{ item[0] }} - {{ session.get('product_name', '') }} - {{ session.get('product_code', '') }} - {{ item[1] }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    
    <form method="POST" action="/unique">
        <button type="submit">Unique</button>
    </form>

    {% if show_second_input %}
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="second-input-modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
            <h1>Enter Second Input</h1>
            <form id="second-input-form" onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
                <input type="text" id="user_input_2" name="user_input_2" required>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            <p id="error-message-modal" style="color: red;"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Script to handle the modal -->
<script>
    // Set focus on the first input box when the page loads
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('user_input_1').focus();
        // Check if the second input modal should be shown on page load
        showModal();
    });

    // Function to show the modal and set focus on the second input box
    function showModal() {
        const modal = document.getElementById("second-input-modal");
        modal.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('user_input_2').focus();
    }

    // Function to close the modal and set focus on the first input box
    function closeModal() {
        const modal = document.getElementById("second-input-modal");
        modal.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('user_input_1').focus();
    }

 // Function to reset focus on the first input box after successful form submission
 function resetFocusOnFirstInput() {
    closeModal(); // Close the modal
    document.getElementById('user_input_1').focus(); // Set focus on the first input box
}

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally

    const user_input_2 = document.getElementById("user_input_2").value;
    const formData = new FormData(); // Create a new FormData object
    formData.append('user_input_2', user_input_2); // Add the user_input_2 field to the form data

    fetch("/check_second_input", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData, // Use the formData object as the request body
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        if (data.error) {
            document.getElementById("error-message-modal").innerText = data.error;
            // Close the modal in case of an invalid input
            closeModal();
        } else {
            if (!data.already_added) {
                // If the input is valid and not already added, reset focus on the first input box
                resetFocusOnFirstInput();
                // Refresh the list of added inputs
                updateAddedInputsList();
            } else {
                // If the input is valid but already added, show the error message without closing the modal
                document.getElementById("error-message-modal").innerText = data.error;
            }
        }
    });
}

// Function to update the list of added inputs dynamically
function updateAddedInputsList() {
    // Fetch the updated page content from the server using the same endpoint that renders the index.html template
    fetch("/", {
        method: "GET",
    })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((html) => {
        // Create a temporary div element to extract the list content from the fetched HTML
        const tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
        tempDiv.innerHTML = html;

        // Find the list container element and replace the current list content with the updated content
        const listContainer = document.querySelector("ul");
        listContainer.innerHTML = tempDiv.querySelector("ul").innerHTML;
    });
}
</script>

{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to use document.getElementById('user_input_1').focus() function but it's focusing on 1st inputbox, only when wrong input is entered then focus is being set correctly.

Comment: use [tabindex="-1"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)  and also [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) with native [showModal()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) method...